# Integrate the keypress function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, keypress

In order to send automatic message (in a canal) in Javascript, I would like to simulate the "Enter" physical button after the "test" message. I have difficulties to integrate the keypress function.

Here is the core of the program :

```
  setInterval(() => {
    client.channels.cache.get('id').send("test", Keypress=Enter);
  }, 50);
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: What kind of channel is this?

Comment: @Brad, this is the identifier of a Discord channel.